# Running a file with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I'm trying to run an mp3 or a txt file(or any type) with python.
I tried os.system, but it didn't work because: zsh permission denied error.I tried to fix the error but I couldn't.
I tried exec, also didn't work.
any other options?

```
 def openbutton():
        if item[-2::] == "py":
            filename = pypr0list.get(pypr0list.curselection())
            os.system(f"python3 pypr0/{filename}")
        else:
            filename =pypr0_list2.get(pypr0_list2.curselection())
            os.system(f"./pypr0/{filename}")
```

first if statement works fine.problem is the 2nd one.

```
sh: ./pypr0/mtrx_scores: Permission denied
```

I use Mac & python3

Comment: What do you mean by "run"? mp3s and test files are not executable, so they cannot be run in the usual sense.

Comment: opening them.When the user click to the button, the txt file or mp3 file gets opened.

Comment: you need to use `xdg-open` on linux and  `open` in mac os. `os.system(f"open  ./pypr0/{filename}")`

Answer (score 0):

```
os.system(f"open  ./pypr0/{filename}")
```

Comment: `open` doesn't exist on many systems, so this won't always work. It also won't solve the author's use case of not having executable permissions on the executable file

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.